# Android Hide Title Bar With Removing Appcompat Theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

ManinActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
     >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I tried

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

feature but it just won't work ! i don't able to find out why.

but when i use

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

it just worked !!!   but i don't want to use Theme can i do it pragmatically ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to do that

1. Set below lines to your styles.xml

   ```
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   ```

Or

2. Set below lines in your ActionBarActivity file.

   ```
   getSupportActionBar().hide();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```